# Cassandra data modeling for social network with follower and following actions

Tags: database, cassandra, data-modeling

I want to know anybody can describe how should be Cassandra data modeling for a social network that allow its users to follow each other, and has timeline and some common features that are in social networks like Twitter.

I found [twissandra](https://github.com/twissandra/twissandra) on Github but that was confusing for me. 
Please if you can describe how following and follower tables should be in Cassandra or provide links to tutorials

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite relational databases schema design in which the queries that will be performed have a major impact only in the context of optimization, **schema design for Cassandra is query oriented**: this means that you need first to figure out the kind information you will ask for in order to be able to design an effective Cassandra instance. A wrong schema design can kill Cassandra's performances.

Therefore, regarding your question, you should first have a complete picture of your context, and then go back to the design phase.

I have personally found really useful the material provided by [Datastax Academy](https://academy.datastax.com/). They are free, you will need only to register. I would suggest you to first take a look at the Cassandra system architecture if you are not familiar with it in order to fully understand the schema design choices, and then look at the main design principles.

Regarding the methodology to be used, I don't think there's an established one right now. I would suggest using the **Chebotko Diagrams** which are well explained in this [article](http://www.cs.wayne.edu/andrey/papers/TR-BIGDATA-05-2015-CKL.pdf).